How to reset IMAP subscriptions
A bit of background.
While moving a substantial amount of folders in Thunderbird a colleague of mine lost contact with the outlook.com servers. Since then he's seeing some folder subtrees in grey italics. The interaction with those folders is problematic, to put it mildly.
A workaround is to uncheck 'Show only subscribed folders' box in Account Settings>Server Settings>Advanced. Doing this hides the problematic folders and the UI shows what's actually on server.
I would like to find a proper solution. I know I want to set/reset the folder subscriptions but the Thunderbird interface is fooled by the corrupted data it receives from the server. How may I set/reset the folder subscriptions (with Thunderbird or otherwise)?
The only strict requirement that comes to my mind is that the tool has to authenticate with Oauth2 to work with Outlook 365.

To reset your IMAP subscriptions, you can follow these steps:

In Outlook:

1.Open Outlook and navigate to the Mail section.
2.In the Navigation Pane, right-click the top folder for your IMAP account.
3.Click on "IMAP Folders."
4.Click "Query."
5.Select the folder you want to reset and click "Subscribe" or "Unsubscribe."
6.If you have created a new folder on the mail server in another application or using a web browser, and the new folder doesn’t appear in the IMAP Folders dialog box, you can update the folder list by right-clicking the top folder for your IMAP account and clicking "Update Folder List".
More information: Choose which IMAP account folders appear in Outlook - Microsoft Support

In Thunderbird:

1.Open Thunderbird and select the account that you want to reset the IMAP subscriptions for.
2.From the top menu, select Tools > Account Settings.
3.In the left-hand pane, select Server Settings.
4.Under the Advanced section, click on the IMAP Server Settings button.
5.Click on the Reset Subscriptions button. This will reset your IMAP subscriptions, causing Thunderbird to re-sync with the email server.
In addition, there is a similar thread you may refer to: IMAP-Like System with Folders/Subscriptions in Exchange

If the answer is helpful, please click "Accept Answer" and kindly upvote it. If you have extra questions about this answer, please click "Comment".
Best,
Joan

Unfortunately those options are not available in Thunderbird 115 and 128, nor in an Outlook that is connected via exchange protocol. And Outlook cannot connect via IMAP to the 365 servers, or at least I couldn't make it connect, it lacks Oauth2.

Thunderbird (How To) Configure Modern Authentication (OAuth2): Navigate to Account Settings > Server Settings > Security Settings > Authentication Method and select OAuth2 from the Authentication Method dropdown. Navigate to Outgoing Server on the left-hand panel of the account settings screen. Select the Office365 (Microsoft) SMTP server and click edit on the right-hand side.

Thunderbird has been configured with Oauth2 right from the start, it is Outlook that does not have the option.

Thanks for rectify.
